# The following code does not output correct time required to execute it

Tags: c, time, clock

I expect the following code to output a time taken to execute code to be approximately 5 seconds.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
 
int main() {
    clock_t start, end;

    /* Store start time here */
    start = clock();
    
    /* Do 5 seconds of work */
    sleep(5);

    /* program logic ends here */
    end = clock();

    printf("start: %f\n", (double)start);
    printf("end: %f\n", (double)end);
    
    /* Get the time taken by program to execute in seconds */
    double duration = ((double)end - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
     
    printf("duration: %f, CPS: %li\n", duration, CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    printf("Time taken to execute in seconds : %f\n", duration);
    return 0;
}
```

But I get following output:

```
start: 1097.000000
end: 1144.000000
duration: 0.000047, CPS: 1000000
Time taken to execute in seconds : 0.000047
```

Can someone please explain why the `Time taken to execute in seconds` is not `5` seconds?

Answer (score 2):

The `clock()` function does not measure elapsed time, it measures CPU time. The system call uses 47 micro-seconds of CPU time for your process, including the overhead of the `clock()` function, which is plausible albeit a bit long.

Use POSIX function `gettimeofday()` on compatible systems for precise wall clock measurements, or `timespec_get()` defined in `<time.h>` if available (C11 and later).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: the OP uses `#include <unistd.h>` so I assumed POSIX compatibility.